# そういうことです vs そういうことになります

Tags: usage

In a mystery story I was reading, a revelation is uncovered that changes the perception of the case. One of the characters then asks, "では, ...... というのですか?". I removed parts of the actual line to avoid spoilers, but he was creating a hypothesis based on the new information.

Another responds: "そういうことになります". My question is, why use なる in this case? Is there any difference in nuance between that and そういうことです?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> そういうことになります

is roughly 'Yes, it would mean that.', because なる means become.

On the other hand,

> そういうことです

becomes 'Yes, it is.'

Since they are speaking based on uncovered evidence, the evidence would mean -> "that". Also, this happens because it is an answer to a question, or in this case the section of

> では, ...... というのですか?

Another explanation may be that the author is trying to add a voice to a character. He may be trying to portray a character that makes sentences overly complicated or formal.